# Непонятный перенос строки

Tags: wordpress

Изменил пару строк в файле шаблона футера, лишних переносов строк никаких нет! Обновил сайт в браузере, перед футером откуда-то появился перенос строки. Что это может быть? Я вообще в недоумении.

Comment: Хоть какие-нибудь коды и скриншоты можно выложить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда изменял на хостинге файл его сохранило в UTF-8 с BOM...